# Fill an amount of fields based on what months are involved

Tags: apex

so what I am trying to do is following:

I have an object with one field for every month, so January__c, Februrary__c and so on.

Now im trying to fill only some of these fields based on whether the month is included inbetween the start and end date of the opportunity. The amount that every month field should be filled with is identical.

So basically im trying to do something like:
if 03.2022 is included in Opp date range, then fill field March__c with the value.
The value is already given. Years can be ignored as they are handled already

Im struggling to find a way to let the code do this dynamically without having to hardcode every month with some kind of
if(startDate.month() < 3){
march__c = value;
}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic Apex for this. First, start off with a List of fields:

```
sObjectField[] monthFields = new sObjectField[] {
    Opportunity.January__c,
    Opportunity.February__c,
    Opportunity.March__c,
    Opportunity.April__c,
    Opportunity.May__c,
    Opportunity.June__c,
    Opportunity.July__c,
    Opportunity.August__c,
    Opportunity.September__c,
    Opportunity.October__c,
    Opportunity.November__c,
    Opportunity.December__c
};
```

*Note: This presumes the fields are on Opportunity. You've mentioned another unnamed object; just change the Opportunity bits above to the appropriate object.*

Now, you can iterate over the months to populate, and choose the appropriate field:

```
// Adjust by 1 because lists are 0-indexed
Integer startMonth = startDate.month() - 1;
Integer endMonth = endDate.month() - 1;
// Just a placeholder based on your question
Decimal whateverAmount = calculateValue();
// Assume "record" below is the record you're populating...
for(Integer currentMonth = 0; currentMonth < 12; currentMonth++) {
  if(startMonth <= currentMonth && currentMonth <= endMonth) {
    record.put(monthFields[currentMonth], whateverAmount);
  } else {
    record.put(monthFields[currentMonth], 0);
  }
}
```

If you're fine with null values, you can choose to do that as well.

```
for(Integer currentMonth = startMonth; currentMonth <= endMonth; currentMonth++) {
  record.put(monthFields[currentMonth], whateverAmount);
}
```

You could also use dates natively, but this is slightly worse performance overall, and probably overkill for your use case, but I'll include it here. We'll adjust the `monthsArray` to match the values from `month()`.

```
sObjectField[] monthFields = new sObjectField[] {
    null, // There is no zeroth month
    Opportunity.January__c,
    Opportunity.February__c,
    Opportunity.March__c,
    Opportunity.April__c,
    Opportunity.May__c,
    Opportunity.June__c,
    Opportunity.July__c,
    Opportunity.August__c,
    Opportunity.September__c,
    Opportunity.October__c,
    Opportunity.November__c,
    Opportunity.December__c
};
```

Now we can iterate over the months:

```
Integer year = Date.today().year(); // Or whatever year you're calculating
Date january = Date.newInstance(year, 1, 1);
Date december = Date.newInstance(year, 12, 1);
for(Date currentDate = january; january <= december; currentDate = currentDate.addMonths(1)) {
  if(startDate <= currentDate && currentDate <= endDate) {
    record.put(monthFields[currentDate.month()], whateverAmount);
  } else {
    record.put(monthFields[currentDate.month()], 0);
  }
}
```